# Как понять что в данный код безопасен для многопоточной среды?

Tags: java, concurrency

Добрый день. Прошу подсказать как получается что данный код безопасный для многопоточной среды.  Кусок кода взят из книжки Java concurrency in practice. Метод service не синхронизирован. Предполагаю что в данном методе возможен race condition. Прошу знатоков пояснить

```
@ThreadSafe
public class VolatileCachedFactorizer implements Servlet {
    private volatile OneValueCache cache = new OneValueCache(null, null);

    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) {
        BigInteger i = extractFromRequest(req);
        BigInteger[] factors = cache.getFactors(i);
        if (factors == null) {
            factors = factor(i);
            cache = new OneValueCache(i, factors);
        }
        encodeIntoResponse(resp, factors);
    }
}
```

Comment: никак, потому что он опасен для многопоточной среды

Comment: @Igor прошу пояснить почему вы так думаете. Мне кажется что данный кусок                                                                                                if (factors == null) {
         factors = factor(i);
         cache = new OneValueCache(i, factors);
         }                                                                                      
        атоммарный соответсвенно из за этого вышеописанный код возможно безопасен

Comment: что такое "атоммарный кусок"? Поле `cache` может быть изменено любым потоком в любой момент.

Comment: "что такое "атоммарный кусок"?" 'это check-then-act

Comment: хм, не сталкивался с таким определением :)

Comment: я тоже не сталкивался но в книжке об этом написано много слов и очень упоротым образом без пояснений я вот надеялся на помощь знатоков)

Comment: Безопасен ) Как вы себе представляете гонку в данном случае? `volatile` обеспечивает видимость, если другой поток затрет ссылку. Сам `OneValueCache` внутри иммутабелен. Внутри `if` чтение из cache не происходит. Даже если 100 потоков одновременно ломанутся в `if` просто кто-то из них будет последним и оставит свое значние в кэше.

Comment: безопасен, если не считать возможное повторное вычисление factor несколькими потоками. в данном коде нет гарантии что несколько потоков не зайдут в if. т.к. этот блок не синхронизирован и null могут увидеть сколь угодно много тредов. зайдя они посчитают factor и присвоят значение. после чего данная ситуация повториться уже не сможет.

Answer (score 3):

Данный код безопасен для многопоточной среды по той простой причине, что класс `OneValueCache` является *immutable*, то есть его внутреннее состояние после его создания изменить невозможно. Если залезть в кишки то класс декларирован как:

```
public class OneValueCache {
    private final BigInteger lastNumber;
    private final BigInteger[] lastFactors;

    public OneValueCache(BigInteger i,
                         BigInteger[] factors) {
        lastNumber = i;
        lastFactors = Arrays.copyOf(factors, factors.length);
    }

    public BigInteger[] getFactors(BigInteger i) {
        if (lastNumber == null || !lastNumber.equals(i))
            return null;
        else
            return Arrays.copyOf(lastFactors, lastFactors.length);
    }
}
```

Видно, что приватные члены класса декларированы как `final`, то есть неизменяемые. А возвращает он свою копию.

Comment: Кстати, получается что `new OneValueCache(null, null);` упадет